# can i use pyroCMS for multilanguage, and multiuser project?

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I need 1 suggestion, This is best platform for my question so i post here.

I think i will use PyroCMS for my new project.

Project has following features:

1. Multilagnguage in front end
2. User management
3. super Admin, country admin, advertisement admin
4. In frontend users export_type and import_type.

Can i use PyroCMS for this project? I need to make fast develop this. or can i do with core?? what you suggest.

I am bigner in PyroCMS, but i am good in Codeigniter.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your project features:

1. Multilingual in front end - PyroCMS has built in multilingual support.
2. User management - Yup, you can extend Users Module as per your need
3. And use Groups Module to create respective (super Admin, country admin, advertisement admin) authentication hierarchy.
4. In frontend users export_type and import_type - can you clarify it further ? if it's about user type (Groups Module as I mentioned in 3) - it's doable.

Can i use PyroCMS for this project?

- Definitely. PyroCMS would be perfect base for your project and will help you build your project at speed. The more I look into PyroCMS the more I feel like it's Codeigniter made easier. Also, Pyro community is very supportive.

Check these links:

1. To understand PyroCMS basics, module structure and module development: http://bhu1st.blogspot.com/2010/09/hello-world-pyrocms-module.html
2. Pyro - Theming, Module & Widget Creation guide and sample code: http://echo.semicolondev.com/

Answer (score 1):

Also the multilingual solution for pyro is that you make multiple subdomains for each language and make multiple sites. Which is problem if you want to share the user database. One domain multilanguage site is a little more dificult but also possible. You can read more about it in this post: https://www.pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/16237

Despite this i also suggest Pyro for the project and for others also :)

Answer (score 1):

In the pyro modules you can have roles which set the permissions, using this along with a users helper you can then have in your module

```
if(user_has_role('super_user')){ 
    // do stuff 
}
```

Sample module : https://github.com/pyrocms/sample
http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/developers/addons/modules/basic-structure